# Assembly language optimizer

Tags: assembly, compilation, arm

When you compile a c++ or any other compiled language there is an optimizer that runs and rewrites some of the code in a more efficient way.  Since you don't compile assembly or arm assembly in the sense you that you do a compiled language, is there an optimizer running, or does the computer run exactly what you type?

Comment: Usually while programming in ASM you want to be sure the binary output is exactly as you wrote it. Can be a bit more tricky with some pseudo instructions saving you some typing, like for example loading immediate constants on fixed-word RISC CPUs, where the assembler itself figures out how to split/combine the load instructions to get the final constant. But generally any unexpected modification of machine code is not wanted, so optimizer would be quite pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this snippet assembled with `nasm -f elf64 -O0` no optimization

```
    section .rodata
  Prompt:   db  'Prompting Text', 0

        section .text
        global  _start    
           
  _start:   xor     rax, rax
            mov     rsi, Prompt
            jmp     Done
            nop
            nop
            nop
            nop
    Done:   xor     rdi, rdi
            mov     eax, 60
            syscall
```

Resulting object code is this;

```
000  4831C0            xor rax,rax
003  48BE000000000000  mov rsi,0x0
         -0000
00D  E904000000        jmp qword 0x16
012  90                nop
013  90                nop
014  90                nop
015  90                nop
016  4831FF            xor rdi,rdi
019  B83C0             mov eax,0x3c
01E  0F05              syscall
020
```

Assembled with default optimization `nasm -f elf64` and the only thing that happened is that assembler figures out that the jump is within 128 bytes so it changed it to short, thus saving 3 bytes.

```
00  4831C0            xor rax,rax
03  48BE000000000000  mov rsi,0x0
         -0000
0D  EB04              jmp short 0x13
0F  90                nop
10  90                nop
11  90                nop
12  90                nop
13  4831FF            xor rdi,rdi
16  B83C000000        mov eax,0x3c
1B  0F05              syscall
1D
```

Modify source to force optimization without the assembler option being set

```
        section .rodata
  Prompt:   db  'Prompting Text', 0

        section .text
        global  _start     
           
  _start:   xor     eax, eax
            mov     esi, Prompt
            jmp     short Done
            nop
            nop
            nop
            nop
    Done:   xor     edi, edi
            mov     eax, 60
            syscall
```

and the result is;

```
00  31C0              xor eax,eax
02  BE00000000        mov esi,0x0
07  EB04              jmp short 0xd
09  90                nop
0A  90                nop
0B  90                nop
0C  90                nop
0D  31FF              xor edi,edi
0F  B83C000000        mov eax,0x3c
14  0F05              syscall
16
```

This is different for different assemblers, but my contention is as @Ped7g has already pointed out, best to know the instruction set so there is a direct correlation between what you've written and object code.

In case you're not aware a lot of instructions sign extend into 64 bits, that's why `xor eax, eax` yields the same result as `xor rax, rax` but saves 1 byte.

Comment: Writing a 32-bit register always [*zero*-extends into the full 64-bit register](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-most-x64-instructions-zero-the-upper-part-of-a-32-bit-register).  (i.e. zeros the upper 32 bits).  If you want 32->64 sign extension, you have to use an instruction, e.g. MOVSXD r64, r/m32.

Comment: Some assemblers also optimize `mov rax, 1234` (7 bytes: REX + opcode + modRM + imm32) into `mov eax, 1234` (5 bytes: opcode + imm32), but some don't.  I forget if it's just for MOV, or if some will also optimize `xor rax,rax` for you, too.